# How to test ember-data has been committed to server?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, jasmine

I have a model that saves to my server via the ember-data rest adapter.

How do I test the data is being sent and returned correctly to the server by stubbing or mocking the commit functionality of ember-data,  without re-testing what ember-data is already tested for?

Preferably in Jasmine!

Comment: What do you mean by 'being sent and return correctly'? Do you care about request/reply correctly handled? JSON content formatted, populated as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a unit test you should never use a real client server communication. Normally you would mock the XMLHttpRequest implementation of your browser.

There a bunch of tools like [jasmine-fake-ajax](https://github.com/mileskin/jasmine-fake-ajax) or [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server). Both override the XHR implementation of the browser and simulate a server. So you can set a route and what should be return. Both can be very granularly adjusted, so you can check if the for type, content-type or set the http response code.

```
{
    setUp: function () {
        this.xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
        var requests = this.requests = [];

        this.xhr.onCreate = function (xhr) {
            requests.push(xhr);
        };
    },

    tearDown: function () {
        this.xhr.restore();
    },

    "test should fetch comments from server" : function () {
        var callback = sinon.spy();
        myLib.getCommentsFor("/some/article", callback);
        assertEquals(1, this.requests.length);

        this.requests[0].respond(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                                 '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]');
        assert(callback.calledWith([{ id: 12, comment: "Hey there" }]));
    }
}
```